# Retrofit baseUrl with parameters

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I get a URL from server with parameters like the following:

```
http://example/?p1=a&p2=b
```

Which will be the server address I will send request.

when I use the following code to make a new retrofit.

```
retrofit.newBuilder().baseUrl(url).build();
```

In the **Interceptor**:

```
Request oldRequest = chain.request();
Logger.e("url:" + oldRequest.url());
```

In the **Log:**

```
url:http://example/
```

But I want to make the **baseUrl** like :

```
http://example/?p1=a&p2=b
```

**NOT** :

```
http://example/
```

So is there some ways to make the baseUrl with parameters?

Comment: How did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, here is your generator class, which may look like this .

```
public class ServiceGenerator {  
    public static String apiBaseUrl = "http://example/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(apiBaseUrl);

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient =
            new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    // No need to instantiate this class.
    private ServiceGenerator() {
    }

    public static void changeApiBaseUrl(String newApiBaseUrl) {
        apiBaseUrl = newApiBaseUrl;

        builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .baseUrl(apiBaseUrl);
    }

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, AccessToken token) {
        String authToken = token.getTokenType().concat(token.getAccessToken());
        return createService(serviceClass, authToken);
    }

    // more methods
    // ...
}
```

After that you can use it in following way in your activity or fragmen

```
public class DynamicBaseUrlActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "CallInstances";
    private Callback<ResponseBody> downloadCallback;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_upload);

        downloadCallback = new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "server contacted at: " + call.request().url());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "call failed against the url: " + call.request().url());
            }
        };

        // first request
        FileDownloadService downloadService = ServiceGenerator.create(FileDownloadService.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> originalCall = downloadService.downloadFileWithFixedUrl();
        originalCall.enqueue(downloadCallback);

        // change base url
        ServiceGenerator.changeApiBaseUrl("http://example/?p1=a&p2=b");

        // new request against new base url
        FileDownloadService newDownloadService = ServiceGenerator.create(FileDownloadService.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> newCall = newDownloadService.downloadFileWithFixedUrl();
        newCall.enqueue(downloadCallback);
    }
}
```

For more info check [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-change-api-base-url-at-runtime-2)

Comment: it won't work,the method **baseUrl()** will not contain parameters,it can change baseUrl,but still lost parameters in the url in your way.All I want is thAt when send request,don't lose parameters in the url.

Comment: I have edited my answer, an important part was missing .

Answer (score 0):

you need use HttpUrl

```
   HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
                  .scheme("https")
                  .host("www.google.com")
                  .addPathSegment("search")
                  .addQueryParameter("q", "polar bears")
                  .build();

retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
               .baseUrl(url)
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               .client(httpClient)
               .build();
```